# Developp concatenation function

Tags: functions

Challenge: find the function $conc(a, b)$ resulting in the concatenation of the number a and b.
Example:
$$conc(1234, 56) = 123456$$

Comment: Perhaps this would have been better written as "find a closed form for the function" instead of "find the function". You've already given a valid definition of the function, so the function has already been "found".

Comment: @TannerSwett Let's say 'find the algebric form of ...'

Comment: "Closed form" is a better term to use than "algebraic form". "Closed form" is common terminology, but I don't think I've ever heard "algebraic form".

Answer (score 0):

Answer

> We assume that very simple function counting the digit amount in a number :
>  $$f(x)\left \{ 0 \right \}=1+\left\lfloor log_{10}x \right\rfloor$$
>
>  Now it's pretty simple :
>  $$conc(a, b)\left \{ 0 \right \} = a * 10^{1+\left\lfloor log_{10}b \right\rfloor} + b$$
>
>  Example:
>  $$conc(1234, 56) = 1234 * 10^{1+\left\lfloor log_{10}56 \right\rfloor} + 56$$
>  $$conc(1234, 56) = 123456$$

Comment: You should exclude $b= 0$ because this will never work on something like $\mathrm{conc}(1,0)$ to create $10$.

Comment: You have a typo in your formula for $conc(a,b).$  What is $x?$

Comment: @saulspatz my bad it's $b$

Comment: @Randall sure, I'll correct that

Comment: I don't know what your {0} notation is supposed to mean. If you want to say that $0$ is not a permitted value for $x$, then standard notation for that would be something like: $f(x)=1+\left\lfloor log_{10}x \right\rfloor \qquad (x \ne 0)$

Comment: @TannerSwett Ok thanks I learnt that in school but idk if it was let's say "conventionnal"